# How can I correct field values acctstoptime left with NULL through log details?

Tags: radius

I was cleaning up the radacct table of records for more than 30 days, and since the database server is MariaDB 5, the transaction locked the table, stopping all wifi in the company (if it was MariaDB 10 had not blocked). Then my boss saw 200 acctstoptime with NULL values ​​and asked me to fix by retrieving the values ​​in a details log of the day. But in details acctstartime is not equal to the value registered in the radius bank, and the last record of details is from 13:41:27. There is something wrong with all this, because the records with acctstoptime NULL started at 04:41:22, and I ran the 12:27 cleanup script. The first user, for example, since signing in 04:41:22, has closed and opened several more times until 13:41:27. Does these NULL have anything to do with my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the wrong records through AcctSessionId, which is in the radacct table and in the details of the controllers. So, even though the radius was unable to save the correct amount in the bank, the controller registered it in the day's details. I updated all the wrong records.